# How could one change the catcodes inside the definition of an environment?

Tags: macros

I tried to find a clever and robust way to use non-letter symbols like `%, _, ], [` etc.inside the definition of an environment. I tried for example to change  `[` and `]` to letters for using them locally. The following code worked well

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\[=11
\catcode`\]=11
\def\[a{some unicode character}
\def\]m{something else}

\[a\]m
\endgroup
```

but when I tried to roll up the above code into an special enviroment like

```
\newenvironment{newaccents}{\begingroup%
\catcode`\[=11%
\catcode`\]=11%
\def\[a{some unicode character}
\def\]m{something else}
}{%
\catcode`\[=12%
\catcode`\]=12%
 \endgroup}
```

the TeX comlains with

```
Undefined control sequence.
 \begin{newaccents}\[a
                           \end{newaccents}
```

So my questions is: How one could change in a local special  way  the codes of non-letters characters so that they can  to  be used inside the definition of local-defined  commands?

Comment: If `\[a` is a command, I don't understand why you want to change the catcodes of `\[` etc. `\def\[a{foo}` works, but I don't recommend it (again). The `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair isn't necessary

Comment: not related to the problem in the question, but you have `%`  at the ends of exactly the wrong lines. You need a space after 11 and 12 to terminate the number so should not have `%` there, space is ignored after a command token so you don't need `%` after `\begingroup` but conversely you do want `%` to hide the space tokens after `character}` and `else}`

Comment: @David Carlisle. You are right! But I dont' understand why such definitions like \[a above does not work locally.... I know that they a special meaning inside math mode so I don't dare to define them globally

Comment: @Danid Carlisle I tried to remove the % as you suggested and I think it WORKED! Thank you again

Comment: I hope you will never have to use a command or environment with optional argument in your environment. One get quite interesting errors e.g. with `\parbox[t]{5cm}{abc}`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you *really* want to do it, you need a two-step approach: first define the commands you want under the right category code setup

```
\begingroup
\catcode`[=11 \catcode`]=11
\gdef\[a{foo}
\gdef\]m{baz}
\endgroup
```

Then you can define the environment so that it changes the category codes:

```
\newenvironment{newaccents}
  {\catcode`[=11 \catcode`]=11 }
  {}
```

The reason why your attempt fails is that when you do

```
\newenvironment{newaccents}{\begingroup%
\catcode`\[=11%
\catcode`\]=11%
\def\[a{some unicode character}
\def\]m{something else}
}{%
\catcode`\[=12%
\catcode`\]=12%
 \endgroup}
```

TeX has already absorbed the tokens in the three arguments to `\newenvironment` under a regime where `[` and `]` have category code 12, so they cannot be changed any more.

The global definitions I give in the first code block have no influence on usage outside the `newaccents` environment, where the category code of `[` and `]` is 12.  You can still use `\[` and `\]` with their original meaning within the `newaccents` environment, provided you ensure they're followed by a space.

In any case, you should recall that an environment where category code changes are performed cannot be used in the argument to a command.

---

There is a different strategy for obtaining a similar result without category code changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareTextCommand{\NAlbrack}{T1}{?} % default is not really defined
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\NAlbrack}{T1}{a}{foo}
% other composites of the form \[x

\DeclareTextCommand{\NArbrack}{T1}{?} % default is not really defined
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\NArbrack}{T1}{m}{baz}
% other composites of the form \]x

\newenvironment{newaccents}
  {\let\[\NAlbrack \let\]\NArbrack}
  {}

\begin{document}

\[a=b\]

\begin{newaccents}
Does \[a print `foo'?

Does \]m print `baz'?
\end{newaccents}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This of course means `\[` and `\]` cannot be used for displays, but I don't think it's a problem for your application.

I used `T1` as the font encoding, but you can use `\encodingdefault`, provided the code is after loading the package for font encodings, be it `fontenc` or `fontspec`.

The trick is to define a command `\NAlbrack` that can look forward for a declared combination, in this case an `a`. If it finds it, it prints whatever you defined the combination to be, otherwise it prints a `?` (just an arbitrary choice, you can define it to do something else in case of no predefined combinations).

In the body of `newaccents`, I simply change `\[` to be the same as `\NAlbrack`.

Comment: I tried your code and I face the following problem :Command \NAlbrack unavailable in encoding EU1

Comment: @kornaros How can I guess you're using XeLaTeX? Change `T1` into `EU1` (and, of course, load neither `fontenc` nor `inputenc`). Better yet, change `T1` into `\encodingdefault`, so the file will be compatible also with LuaLaTeX. Note that the code must go after loading `fontspec`.

Comment: I use \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setmainfont{GFS Neohellenic} inmy preample. Also I see a strange ? in your  \DeclareTextCommand{\NAlbrack}{T1}{?} Maybe my browser does not print this character correctly! Is really a ? or some other symbol? Also could you please explain your code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kornaros What I gave is just a proof of concept, given that your question was very generic. But changing `T1` into `\encodingdefault` as suggested is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Change the catcodes temporarily, for the duration of your definition; then they go back to default, until your environment re-activates them the way you do now.

```
\catcode`[=11
\catcode`]=11
\newenvironment{newaccents}{
      \catcode`[=11
      \catcode`]=11
\def\[a{(Accent)}
}{}
\catcode`[=12
\catcode`]=12
```

Note that `\begin` will begin a group for you; and since catcodes are local, there's no need to set them back by hand.

**Edit:** *Of course* `\global\newenvironment` doesn't work. Fixed now, sorry for the distraction.

Comment: `\global\newenvironment`? Oh, not going to work; please, try it.

Comment: Thank you for your naswer! I tried to define commands staring with \[ or \] locally because they have a special meaning in math mode eniroment. I dont understand why latex complains with such enviroments. Also the code \newenvironment{newaccents}{\begingroup%
\def\[a{some unicode character}
\def\]m{something else}}{
 \endgroup} have the same problem!!

Comment: Rats. I had my doubts about using `\global` with `\newenvironment`, I should have checked before going offline... but I was busy IRL. I wouldn't quite say it's "completely wrong", though: The main point (in intent at least) is that the catcodes need to be active for both definition and use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point in having cat code changes here: `\[a` is a 'valid' command name, if really needed.

Since all is defined in an environment, `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` aren't needed here at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newenvironment{newaccents}{%\begingroup%
%\catcode`\[=11%
%\catcode`\]=11%
\def\[a{some unicode character}%
\def\]m{something else}%
}{%
%\catcode`\[=12%
%\catcode`\]=12%
% \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{newaccents}
\[a äöü \]m
\end{newaccents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course you don't want to have displayed equations using `\[...\]` in the `newaccents` environment. Note also that you can't have both `\[a` and `\[e`

Comment: You will see the point of the catcode change if you add `\def\[b{some other unicode}`.

Comment: @egreg: I never want to such stuff at all because I don't want to shoot myself into the foot ;-) It's useless code golfing

Answer (score 2):

The following answer doesn't add much to @egreg's answer, but shows an alternative, slightly more compact route to the same result which might possibly be illuminating.

As noted, the crucial thing to know here is that TeX assigns a (catcode, charactercode) pair to every character *once*, when it is *first* read. That means that your `\def\[a` has to happen in a context where `[` will be read with catcode 11.

The second thing to know is that an environment `\begin{foo} ... \end{foo}` expands into (essentially) `\begingroup\foo ... \endfoo\endgroup` (plus some bookkeeping); that is, you can (mostly) define an environment `{foo}` simply by defining the pair of macros `\foo` and `\endfoo`.

Thus:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\[=11 % treat [ as a letter within this group
\gdef\newaccents{% Now define the {newaccents} environment
  \def\[a{foo}% a macro with a two-letter name
  \catcode`\[=11 % make [ a letter within the body of this environment
}
\global\let\endnewaccents=\relax
\endgroup
```

Notice that `\def\[a` happened within the group, so it's interpreted as two *letters*.  The `\gdef` means that the definition of this and of `\foo` ‘escape’ the group.

After that...

```
\begin{document}
Here is text.
\[
E=mc^2.
\]

\begin{newaccents}
  Here is some \[a text, with displayed maths:
  \[ F=ma. \]
\end{newaccents}

\end{document}
```

Doing it this way means that you don't have to wish that `\global\newenvironment` worked.  Also, a difference between this solution and @egreg's (too slight to be much of an advantage) is that `\[a` isn't defined at all, even inaccessibly, outside the `{newaccent}` environment.